# Reactjs: Opening Link in a New Tab works fine in Development but status-code 404 in Production

Tags: reactjs, iis, web-deployment

I am having issue opening a link in a new tab. However, it works fine in development with the following code:

main-menu.js

```
export class ReportsPopover extends Component {
render() {
   var agencyId = AgencyInfo.getSelectedAgencyId();
   var url = '/pqi-graph?agencyId='+ agencyId;
   const menu =
    <Menu>
      <MenuDivider title="Reports" />
        <MenuItem style={{ overflowX: "visible" }} fitted key="Reports" text="Performance Forecast">                              
           <Link to={url} target="_blank" style={{ overflowX: "visible", color: 'black' }}>
                    <MenuItem 
                        fitted key="pqi"
                        text="PQI Graph"/>
           </Link>
       </MenuItem>                
    </Menu>;
```

index.js

```
import PQIGraph from './reports/pqi-graph';
<Route path="/pqi-graph" component={PQIGraph} />
```

Config.json

```
{
  "server": "http://localhost:3001",
  "homeUrl": "http://localhost:3000",
 "pqi-graph": "http://localhost:3000/pqi-graph",
  "dev": true,
  "homepage":  "/"
}
```

Before I put the command `npm run build` I am changing my Config.js file as the following:

```
{
  "server": "http://example.com:3001",
  "homeUrl": "http://example.com/xyz",
 "pqi-graph": "http://example.com/pqi-graph",
  "dev": true,
  "homepage":  "/xyz"
}
```

package.json
   `{"name": "grit-app","homepage": "/xyz",}`

I am putting the contents of my build folder inside the directory `xyz`.
When I try to open the page in production it gives me 404. Any help will be really appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when you host the site in iis you need to use the build folder as the site folder path.

also, you may need to set the react rut using iis URL rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}{URL}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}{URL}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="None" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/path/to/subfolder/index.html" />
            </rule>
```